# LIKE clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, db2-400

IN my stored procedure I have

```
SELECT properName 
FROM nameTable
WHERE properName like '%IN_newName%'
```

But it isn't working on a value that has a space in the first character spot " Name"

I've tried `like IN_newName concat'%'` and also LOCATE(), but I'm not getting any results. I just need to be able to match the values of a string even if there is a space in the front or back and concat doesn't seem to get it. For reference, properName and IN_newName are both CHARACTER(10)

What else can I try here? This is db2 for iSeries jVersion 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
like trim(IN_newName) concat'%'
```

Comment: Ok, but can you trim properName and In_newName ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try:

```
SELECT properName 
FROM nameTable
WHERE properName like CONCAT(LTRIM(IN_newName),'%')
```